# savetrees conflicts with enumitem

Tags: enumitem, incompatibility, savetrees

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[moderate]{savetrees}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start=10]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This works fine, however.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start=10]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The errors look like this:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `moderate` option of [`savetrees`](//ctan.org/pkg/savetrees) redefines lists to remove their indentation. From the `savetrees` documentation:

> The first option, `subtle`, preserves all document layout and merely encourages
>   LaTeX to try harder to pack text onto the page while introducing white space only when absolutely necessary. The second option, `moderate`, additionally reduces paragraph indentation, typesets lists and mathematical displays without indentation or surrounding vertical space, reduces interline spacing, and makes the font slightly narrower, if supported.

Since [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) itself redefines the inner workings of lists, the `moderate` option for `savetrees` is partially incompatible with `enumitem`. That is, you can use `moderate`, but would have to switch the package load order; as such, your lists won't `save` `trees` anymore:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[moderate]{savetrees}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start=10]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```